# Definition of sheaves of principal parts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, sheaf-theory

I am confused with the definition of sheaves of principal parts

As far as I understand, I have the following definitions.

1. [EGA IV. §16] Let $f:X \to S$ be a morphism of schemes and $\Delta: X \to X \times_S X$ the diagonal morphism, which is a locally closed embedding. We have
   short exact sequence over $X$: $$0 \to \mathcal{J} \to \Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0.$$
   Then $\mathcal{P}^n_{X/S}$ is defined as
   $$\mathcal{P}^n_{X/S}:= (\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X})/ \mathcal{J}^{n+1}$$
   The $\mathcal{O}_X$-bi-module structure of $\mathcal{P}_{X/S}^n$ is induced by the two projections $X \times_S X \to X$ (I omit the "obvious" details here). Besides, if $X/S$ is separated, then it's the same as
   $$ \Delta^{-1} \big(\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}/\mathcal{I}^{n+1}\big),$$
   where $\mathcal{I}$ is the kernel of the surjection $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} \to \Delta_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$
2. [Notes on Crystalline Cohomology. Chp 2] We have natural map $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{O}_X$ so that we can take the tensor product of $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S$-algebras: $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X$. Then we have
   $$0\to \mathscr{I} \to \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0 $$
   where $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is the obvious multiplication map. Then we define
   $$\mathscr{P}_{X/S}^n :=\big( \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X\big) / \mathscr{I}^{n+1}.$$
   the bi-module structure is obvious from the tensor product.

**Now my question is**: what's the relation between $\mathscr{P}_{X/S}^n$ and $\mathcal{P}_{X/S}^n$ defined above?

I can check that there is a canonical map 
$$\varphi: \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow\Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}  $$
from the universal property of tensor product. I think $\varphi$ could not be an isomorphism in general. For example, take any point $x \in X$, we have the stalks
$$
\big(\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X\big)_x  = \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{S, f(x)}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}
$$
which may not be a local ring but
$$
\big(\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}\big)_x  = \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X, \Delta(x)}
$$
which is always a local ring. But i guess $\varphi$ may induce an isomorphism between $\mathscr{P}_{X/S}^n$ and $\mathcal{P}_{X/S}^n$.

**Question**: Is that true? If they were not an isomorphic, why do they give the same theory?

Comment: The question is local, so reduce to affine open sets. There this becomes a statement about rings. Can you prove it there?

Comment: (Note that these sheaves are not of differential operators but of jets, which is the dual thing. You should probably edit the title to match the question)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, Thank you! I corrected it. I have encountered name "jet" but I didn't know its definition. I only know the name "principal part". Thanks for pointing it out and now I have something new to know.

Comment: Duplicate of [Sheaves of Principal parts](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20940/sheaves-of-principal-parts) on mathoverflow.